# Unable to use JavaScript Library in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
              "node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
              "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
              "node_modules/vanilla-tilt/src/vanilla-tilt.js" // This ONE!!!
            ]
```

https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/
Vanilla Tilt JS

I am unable to install this library and use it in my component despite declaring it in my package.json file via using npm install. I have tried pasting CDN  link in index.html as well, but both fail to work.

Comment: What happens if you use the dist file instead of the source one ? (`vanilla-tilt/dist/vanilla-tilt.min.js`)

Comment: is your error, that it's not bundled or that you can not use it in your code?

Comment: theres no error in console, but its not working in code either. @argee

Comment: Put the library name in package.json and with version you want to install and do npm install

Comment: will try that DIST @Seblor

Comment: dist file does not work either @Seblor

Comment: it is already added in package.json file @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: Delete packag-lock.json and npm install again

Comment: no luck after that @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: I think we need a codepen or similar

Comment: seems to be working fine on stackblitz example template https://stackblitz.com/edit/vanilla-tilt but does not work with my project. Its 400mb so im unable  to upload it. @Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a js from node_modules in your index.html.
The index.html 'lives' in the browser, the browser has no access to node_modules.

You can try to import from an cdn in your index.html.

Give this a try:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/4.0.2/bootstrap-material-design.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can do the same with the vanilla-tilt.js. Copy it to assets/js folder and try to use this:

```
<script src="assets/js/vanilla-tilt.js"></script>
// or for a quick test:
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js/master/dist/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
```

But:
Disadvantage: these js files will not concatinated (and not minified) by build process.

Comment: Copying the script tag with just .js file does not display error neither does it work. And githubusercontent displays "The resource from ```“https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js/master/dist/vanilla-tilt.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)." ``` in console

Answer (score 0):

Open the node modules and check if they are correctly installed. Once installed you can import the library in your application for example for jquery in component you can do like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

and use `$` and jquery methods

Similarly you can do with other libraries like

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

then use `moment(someValue).format('L')`